# How to fix empty asset issue with PHImageManager in AssetsPickerController iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, assets, avasset, phimagemanager

I am working on `AssetsPickerController` in `Swift` to select multiple `Videos` from `Device gallery`.

Problem: When I am selecting multiple `Videos` or sometimes single `video` then sometimes my `App` is crashing due to Empty `Video Asset`. This is happening 5-10 times, out of 100 times of testing.

Code:

```
@IBAction func openAssetsAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let rootListAssets = AssetsPickerController()
        rootListAssets.didSelectAssets = {(assets: Array<PHAsset?>) -> () in

            for i in 0..<assets.count {

                let myPHAsset = assets[i]

                let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
                options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
                options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

                options.progressHandler = {  (progress, error, stop, info) in
                    print("progress: \(progress)")
                }

                PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: myPHAsset!, options: options, resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) in
                    if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                        let localVideoUrl = urlAsset.url
                        print(localVideoUrl)
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootListAssets)
        present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I checked my best to find the similar issue in StackOverFlow and got some, they are suggesting to use `isNetworkAccessAllowed`, but after setting `isNetworkAccessAllowed`, still I am getting nil `Asset`.

Comment: If anything wrong in my question, I am ready to hear your suggestions. Why downvote?

Comment: What happens if you remove ` options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat` ?

Comment: after removing also, issue is still same.

Comment: In Image, we have synchronous property but its not available for Videos.  I am struggling with this from last 2 days. Please suggest me @ahbou

Comment: @user2786 do you face error like this `_ArrayBuffer._getElementSlowPath(_:)`?

Comment: @chiragshah I am not getting any error, total I am getting correct assets count from didSelectAssets method, but when I am converting PHAssets into Urls then getting nil for some videos. You understand?

Comment: @user2786 Okay got your point

Comment: Have you faced this issue? Please give any idea.

Comment: @user2786 did you find any solution for same.??

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't force unwrap the asset here `forVideo: myPHAsset!`

```
guard 
  let myPHAsset = assets[i] 
else { 
  return 
}
```

Then try setting the deliveryMode to automatic:

```
options.deliveryMode = .automatic
```

EDIT:

To force the download of the asset, we need to specify the version:

```
options.version = .original
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my concern is why asset is giving nil. This solution is basically to avoid the crashing issue but any other solution do we have to get URLs for all selected Videos.

Comment: @user2786 nil means the asset isn't in the library. Force the download by setting it to original

Comment: But for the same Video, sometimes I am getting also or sometimes not :(

Comment: As I'm sure you saw from the multitude of questions on SO, Photos.framework isn't 100% reliable :/ 
The way it handles caching is still a mystery...